# How to remove options from map on selection jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

```
  <form:select id="name1"  
                <form:options items="${questionsMap}"/>
                </form:select>
 <form:select id="name2"  
                <form:options items="${questionsMap}"/>
                </form:select>
 <form:select id="name3"  
                <form:options items="${questionsMap}"/>
                </form:select>
```

The questions map come from enum.Can anyone please help how can I remove the question from the questionsMap after it is selected on the first select and display the unselected ones the second time.

Comment: Do you mean after page loads, if user selects in first drop-down, for second and third same option has to get disabled without page reload?

Comment: Without reoading the page.. I have three input fields for three answers and one submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it on a JSP, as the code there will run on the server side - if you don't want do extra queries to the server... So the best way is to do it with JavaScript. Jquery selectors make this task easy.

Suggestion: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Also, events that might interest you:
http://api.jquery.com/change/

There you can even find a  as example...

Just to put my example here:

```
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
          $( this ).remove();
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes I was thinking to use javascript. But the problem I am having is to remove one item from the map on selection. Do you have any other examples ?

Comment: This will remove from the screen, but if you want to remove from the map on the server site, you can use ajax to send an instruction, the JSP or servlet then can remove it for you.

Comment: Ajax will send an URL and data to the server, without requiring a reload..much like a form would do, but without reloading..is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing options from the drop-down you could simply validate the same options selected and show the error message on submit.

```js
var validateSubmit = function() {
  var errors = [];//trace all errors here

  //fetch selected values from the drop-down starting name attribute with `name`
  var txt = $('select[name^=name]').map(function() {
    return this.value; //get current drop-down selected value
  }).get(); //get all value in array

  $.each(txt, function(i, v) {//loop in the selected values
    if (i !== $.inArray(v, txt)) {//inArray, gives -1 if not found else array index
      errors.push('Cannot select [' + v + '] more than once');
    }
  });

  var submit = 0 === errors.length//true if no errors, else false

  if (!submit) {
    alert(errors.join('\n'));//concat all errors with \n
  }

  return submit;//submit if true, else don't submit
};

$(function() {
  $('#form1').on('submit', validateSubmit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='form1'>
  <select name='name1'>
    <option>JS</option>
    <option>SQL</option>
    <option>XML</option>
  </select>

  <select name='name2'>
    <option>JS</option>
    <option>SQL</option>
    <option>XML</option>
  </select>

  <select name='name3'>
    <option>JS</option>
    <option>SQL</option>
    <option>XML</option>
  </select>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

OR

You could simply validate the same options selected and show the error message on change.

```js
var names;
var validateChange = function() {
  var errors = []; //trace all errors here

  //fetch selected values from the drop-down starting name attribute with `name`
  var txt = names.map(function() {
    return this.value; //get current drop-down selected value
  }).get(); //get all value in array

  $.each(txt, function(i, v) { //loop in the selected values
    if ('' !== v && i !== $.inArray(v, txt)) { //inArray, gives -1 if not found else array index
      errors.push('Cannot select [' + v + '] more than once');
    }
  });

  if (errors.length) {
    alert(errors.join('\n')); //concat all errors with \n
  }
};

$(function() {
  names = $('select[name^=name]');
  names.on('change', validateChange);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='name1'>
  <option value=''>-- Select --</option>
  <option>JS</option>
  <option>SQL</option>
  <option>XML</option>
</select>

<select name='name2'>
  <option value=''>-- Select --</option>
  <option>JS</option>
  <option>SQL</option>
  <option>XML</option>
</select>

<select name='name3'>
  <option value=''>-- Select --</option>
  <option>JS</option>
  <option>SQL</option>
  <option>XML</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is great, but it will reload the page, unless it is in a frame..ajax would have a similar effect, without reloading.

Answer (score 0):

This is a jquery code I made which does exactly this. Also leaves empty values in (if you have "Please select" in the top) and reinserts unselected values. It does it for all select elements on the page, if you need to restrict replace the selector $("select") with a more specific one:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  manageSelectValues();
  $("select").change(manageSelectValues); 
});

function manageSelectValues()
{
  $("select").each(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    if (value) {
      $("select[id!='" + id + "']").find("option").filter(function() { return this.value == value;}).remove();
    }
    $(this).find("option").filter(function() { return this.value != value;}).each(function() {
      var unselValue = $(this).val();
      $("select").filter(function() { return $(this).find("option").filter(function() { return this.value == unselValue;}).length == 0; }).append(
        $('<option></option>').val(unselValue).html(unselValue));
    })
  });
}
```